Magento 2.4.7: Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks
I am facing issue with my pagebuilder on server. I am using apache server for my Magento (2.4.7) instance.
When I first open the category edit page on incognito mode, I open the pagebuilder, add my content and save the category. It works the first time.
If I again open the pagebuilder, update the content and try to save category, it gets stuck with a console error message:
Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks

This issue is also same on other pages where a pagebuilder is added. If I close my incognito tab and open a new one, the same process is repeated, it works the first time and then, it just shows a loader.

I have tried the solutions like, addind missing <item> tags in pagebuilder element in xml file.
I have also made sure there is no other pagebuilder on category edit page which could conflict with each other.

Note: The issue is not there on my local instance with the same codebase. It only appears on live server.

Chrome just released an update and after installing it, I can save the Page Builder content normally. I have not tested with other browsers.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NCOaxO7sKc7wkIEWtrWCx-uJlnAvzw2P/view I installed this patch in magento 2.4.7-p1 but not working for i tried it on 2.4.7 website but it is not working there also.

does the patch work for version 2.4.7-p1 or is there a patch that resolved the issue perfectly for this version

We are also facing same problem and adobe team have shared patch with us and after apply that patch issue is resolved.
If anyone having facing same problem then you can use attached patch file. I hope it works. Thanks.
Patch Link:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NCOaxO7sKc7wkIEWtrWCx-uJlnAvzw2P/view

That patch didn't seem to make any difference for me on 2.4.7. Was there anything else you had to do?

This patch worked on Magento 2.4.5-p8, I just had to remove the last snippet that applies changes to the file vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/web/template/page-builder.html.

ACSD-59582_2.4.7.patch fixed the issue for me on Magento 2.4.7. Thanks.

Same here - we asked the Adobe Support to provide us the patch since it is not yet available via ece-tools. They provided us ACSD-59582_2.4.7.patch which fixes the mentioned issue for us.

Patch was the only thing that worked in 2.4.5-p8

Adobe published a patch fixing this problem.
You can see the patches to apply for different versions here.
For 2.4.7, you need to apply the patch ACSD-52041_2.4.6.patch

for us, it didn't fix the issue - we needed to apply ACSD-59582_2.4.7.patch

This weird issue is present in many Magento versions and there are many fixes available over the internet.
It is related to chrome, not particularly a Magento 2-related issue.
Here are some issues, I hope you will find a related commit that will fix your issue.
Please go through these reference links :
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-28/acsd-48857-unable-to-save-changes-after-editing-with-pagebuilder
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37516
https://github.com/magento/magento2-page-builder/commit/69953bcb7f1ac3a793ec7e0b09fc07e680a80856
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34898
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29977
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28706

Hello Jigar, Thank you, but I am using 2.4.7 which has the patch applied. I do not have multiple builder on page. Also, I am facing the same issue on FireFox as well.

Yes, Magento already fixed this in 2.4.7 but somehow many users still facing this issue as whenever it exceeds 5 seconds it throws this same error :(

I have the same problem with Magento 2.4.7 and different browsers. In previous versions, I never experienced this and did not need to apply any fix.
In my case, the problem started as soon as I updated to Magento 2.4.7

very simple steps need to be followed:
first step is to update ece-tool using this command:
composer update magento/ece-tools --with-dependencies

second step to check the available patches from magento:
vendor/bin/ece-patches status

third step is to add all patches in build section to your .magento.env.yaml
  build:
    SCD_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: 9
    QUALITY_PATCHES:
      - MDVA-30106
      - MDVA-12304
      - MDVA-19640
      - MDVA-15546
      - ACSD-58739
      - ACSD-58141
      - ACSD-58790
      - ACSD-59036
      - ACSD-59514
      - ACSD-60303
      - ACSD-60441

last step is to just run the apply command:
vendor/bin/ece-patches apply

Issue will be resolved.

I'm on 2.4.6-p7 and neither the 2.4.6 nor the 2.4.7 patch worked for me. I ended up having to go with the Quality Patches Tool via composer and got it working using:
ACSD-59514: Fixes the issue where forms in the Admin area with Page Builder throw the Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks. error in the browser console after submitting the form and changes can’t be saved.

Install the latest quality patches package: ./composer require magento/quality-patches
Apply the patch: ./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply ACSD-59514
Clean the cache: ./bin/magento cache:clean

Source: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/tools/commerce-quality-patches/index.html?lang=en
Try that one if your version is compatible and the other patches aren't working!

The patches mentioned above do not apply for the latest 2.4.7, you would have to be on 2.4.6 (maybe I'm doing something wrong but I am using the Quality Patches Tool)
I have tried all other suggestions, none work.
My only work-around for now is to edit Page Builder items (pages, blocks, etc..) using Safari in a private browsing tab. I have tried most other browsers using regular or private and none work and that includes clearing cache, restarting the computer and much more. I don't know why private tab in Safari works on my mac, but so far it is working consistently.
I hope that helps others who are stuck. It just seems that Open Source Magento has become very cumbersome to operate on a production environment. Something is broken with every update. And prior fixed items get re-broken. Very frustrating.
